# Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x8F\x0A#...for column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, unicode, sql-insert, symbols

I am new to `MySQL`. 
I have a column which stores `Unicode character` in `MySQL` table.

I have a code which gets the posts from the `twitter,facebook` etc. and 
insert the `text/symbol` **'as is'** into the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_unicode` (
  `_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `uninoce_Column` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


/* This query WONT work due to SYMBOL:   */
INSERT INTO `tbl_unicode`
  (`_id`,
  `first_name`,
  `uninoce_Column`)
VALUES
  (2,
  'rakesh',
  '最高の休日
#京都#宮津#天の橋立#');


/* This query WORKS FINE */
INSERT INTO `tbl_unicode`
  (`_id`,
  `first_name`,
  `uninoce_Column`)
VALUES
  (1,
  'shekhar',
  '最高の休日
#京都#宮津#天の橋立#');
enter code here
```

[Live Demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/589f0b/1)

So, which datatype or configuration should i do to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

> CHARACTER SET utf8

MySQL's `utf8` charset is not UTF-8. That would be too easy! Instead, it's a limited subset of UTF-8 where only code points up to U+00FFFF, which can be stored in three UTF-8 bytes, are supported.  is U+01F48F, so it doesn't fit in the table's charset.

The *real* UTF-8 character set is known in MySQL (5.5 and later) as `utf8mb4`.

Comment: how to set it? .

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN col_name datatype CHAR SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Answer (score -1):

Use `nvarchar` as datatype for your table fields. `varchar` only stores 8-bit characters while `nvarchar` also stores unicode characters.

Comment: Do we have nvarchar in MYSQL?

Comment: Nope, that's a Microsoft SQL Server data type. It doesn't exist in MySQL.